# The ________ for Business Statistics

Tags: word, english

Your boss wants you to head up a new part of the company that will analyze business statistics. She wants an official name for it like "The Organization for Business Statistics" or "The Business Statistics Council".

She asks you to write a list of 26 words that start with each letter of the alphabet that are loosely synonymous to "organization" or "council". She agrees that there are no such words starting with `h`, `k`, `n`, `q`, `v`, `x`, or `y`, so really she only wants 19 words.

You write this list, choosing words that would not seem out of place in the phrase

> I'm a member of The ________ of/for Business Statistics.

or perhaps

> I have to go to a meeting with the Business Statistics ________.

Sadly, you've lost the list, and only have vague memories about what the words were. You jot down these recollections, knowing they must relate to the words:

```
a: starts with an end
b: holds clothes
c: three sets of double letters
d: math operation
e: more proper to use for music
f: Sam was in one
g: sounds like wine fruit
h: n/a
i: reasearch ___, ___ for technology
j: angry men
k: n/a
l: the red-headed one was fake
m: of magic
n: n/a
o: relates to neatness and tidiness
p: relates to windows
q: n/a
r: Sam was in this too, in a way
s: sounds like Stampy's best friend's name
t: almost a meeting going in the wrong direction
u: one
v: n/a
w: powerful, compound
x: n/a
y: n/a
z: only if it's monkey business
```

You already realize that `o` must be for `organization` because being organized relates to being neat and tidy. **Can you figure out the other 18 words?** (`c` is not necessarily for `council`. The words only contain letters.)

To verify your answer, take the 19 words in order, all in lowercase, and separate them with spaces. e.g.

```
aword bword cword dword eword fword gword iword jword lword mword oword pword rword sword tword uword wword zword
```

The resulting [MD5 hash](http://www.miraclesalad.com/webtools/md5.php) is `6a871238db24d9b1a91fc87f34721963`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hash:

> association bureau committee division ensemble fellowship group institute jury league ministry organization panel ring squad team unit workforce zoo

A is for

> ASSOCIATION (starts with "ass")

B is for

> BUREAU

C is for

> COMMITTEE (there weren't many possibilities!)

D is for

> DIVISION

E is for

> ENSEMBLE - thanks again to **Reticality**.

F is for

> FELLOWSHIP (Lord of the Rings reference)

G is for

> GROUP (sounds like "grape")

I is for

> INSTITUTE ("research institute", "institute for technology")

J is for

> JURY

L is for

> LEAGUE (a **lovely** reference to the Sherlock Holmes story "The Red-headed League"!)

M is for

> MINISTRY (Harry Potter reference) Thanks to **Reticality** for this one, since I've now looked at his answer.

O is for

> ORGANISATION (already mentioned in the OP)

P is for

> PANEL (as in window panel)

R is for

> RING (well, Sam's finger was in it at least!)

S is for

> SQUAD (**Reticality** told me it should sound like "squid".)

T is for

> TEAM (almost "meet" backwards)

U is for

> UNIT

W is for

> WORKFORCE - thanks one final time to **Reticality**.

Z is for

> ZOO

Great puzzle by the way!

Comment: I'm pretty new to puzzling.se so I'm not sure if I should tell you which ones you got correct now or if I should wait for more edits/answers. Advice?.

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies Telling me which ones I got correct is fine. I've spoilertagged them all, so other people can choose whether or not to use that info. (By the way, congrats on getting your other riddle into a nicer form so that it could be answered by someone without enough rep to see deleted answers!)

Comment: Currently your incorrect ones are a, i, and u (not to mention the 9 you haven't done).

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies Now I have something for everything! Can you tell me which ones are wrong?

Comment: Lets see... B, E, W are wrong. U is only slightly wrong. You've got the wrong "sounds like" word for S. The rest are correct.

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies I've edited B and U. Just to be clear, do you mean my final answer for S is wrong but the word it sounds like is right?

Comment: B is not the "official" answer but it works. U is still wrong, think of it in the context of the sample phrases in OP. S is wrong on both accounts.

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies I've updated S and U. The only thing I can think of now for B is BOX or BASKET, which doesn't work. Edit: got it! :-) All three outstanding letters updated then.

Comment: S and U still wrong, but finally the correct B :) S shouldn't be too hard now, and I think you're overcomplicating U.

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies I think I've got both S and U now! Yes - the hash is right. I thought it was wrong, but that was because I used ORGANISATION not ORGANIZATION :-p

Comment: Indeed you do! Your hash is only different because you're spelling organization with an s.

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies Fixed - I'd forgotten to change that at the top!

Answer (score 4):

Here is my answer.

a: starts with an end

> Association (Starts with "ass", an end)

b: holds clothes - wrong

> Body (Actual answer: "Bureau" (of change? as in changing clothes.) By **Rand al'thor**)

c: three sets of double letters

> Committee (Doubles: "m", "t" and "e"

d: math operation

> Division? Like the division of defence or something? Can't think of anything else.

e: more proper to use for music

> Ensemble. As in group (of musicians)

f: Sam was in one

> Fellowship. I think he was Frodo's best friend in tLoTR

g: sounds like wine fruit

> Group, as in Grape (which ferments to wine)  **Rand al'thor** got this.

i: research **_, _** for technology

> Institute. I found many `research institute`s, and some `institute[s] for technology (and management)`

j: angry men

> Jury, the 12 angry men. (Movie)

l: the red-headed one was fake

> League. Used Google's synonyms, so no explanation.

m: of magic

> Ministry (of magic. From Harry Potter I believe)

o: relates to neatness and tidiness

> Organisation. Neat people have this.

p: relates to windows

> Panel

r: Sam was in this too, in a way

> The ring!

s: sounds like Stampy's best friend's name  - Incorrect

> syndicate? (Squad. Again by **Rand al'thor**)

t: almost a meeting going in the wrong direction

> `gniteem` -> `teem` -> `team` (Riddles make the word `backwards` *always* implicitly imply reverse.)

u: one - wrong but close

> Union. As in the union of probability / set theory into 1.
>  (Actually unit. By **Rand al'thor**)

w: powerful, compound

> Workforce? A compound word, who are powerful?

z: only if it's monkey business

> The [thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/corporation?s=t) suggests zoo. And, coincidentally, that's what the other answer says.

Comment: B is not what I was thinking but it actually fits quite well. The shorter J answer is correct (it fits the sample phrases better). For S you have the right Stampy but are way off otherwise. U is wrong (but close). All others are correct.

Comment: I've taken a few of your solutions into my answer, crediting you for each one. I hope you don't mind! I can remove them if you like. Now we just have S and U left to get...

Comment: @Reticality Wait, you're giving away all the answers in your hash string! You don't need to include the string, juct check for yourself if the [MD5 hash value](http://www.miraclesalad.com/webtools/md5.php) is identical to the one I provided. If it is then you know you have the answers exactly right.

Comment: I finally managed to complete it. Thanks for your help! :-) I got E, M, W, and help with S from you.

Comment: @Len It could just be removed. There's really no point in having it unless it's the correct one (which this isn't).